# jquery template display checked for radio button while initializing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using jquery template to display some list of data, I have some radio button controls so after initializing the template radio button not get checked if getting the value as true.
Following is my code for

```
   InitializeUniversityAllocationControl: function (referenceList) {
    if (referenceList != undefined && referenceList != "") {
        var obj = JSON.parse(referenceList.replace(/&quot;/ig, '"'));
        if (obj.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                var ref = new AllocationModel(i);
                //ref.Id = obj[i].Id;
                ref.UnvId = obj[i].UnvId;
                ref.IsAllowed = obj[i].IsAllowed;
                ref.IsDefault = obj[i].IsDefault;
                ref.ListingOnUniversity = obj[i].ListingOnUniversity;

                this.AllocationIndex = i;

                $("#referenceTemplate").tmpl(ref).appendTo("#divUnvAllocationContainer");
                $('#templateContainer' + i).find(".name").val(ref.UnvId);
            }

            this.AllocationIndex = this.AllocationIndex + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

My Html template is like below:

```
     <div class="radio-list">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" value=${IsAllowed} name="AllocatedUniversityList[${Index}].IsAllowed" class="rbIsAllowed" id="AllocatedUniversityList[${index}].isallowed"/>Yes
                    @*@Html.RadioButton("AllocatedUniversityList[${Index}].IsAllowed", true, new { @id = "AllocatedUniversityList[${Index}].IsAllowed", @class = "rbIsAllowed"}) Yes*@

                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" value=${IsAllowed} name="AllocatedUniversityList[${Index}].IsAllowed" class="rbIsAllowed" id="AllocatedUniversityList[${index}].isallowed" />No
                    @*@Html.RadioButton("AllocatedUniversityList[${Index}].IsAllowed", false, new { @id = "AllocatedUniversityList[${Index}].IsAllowed", @class = "rbIsAllowed", }) No*@
                </label>
            </div>
```